# html emmet in php files VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I use html emmet in .php files?
It works in .html files.

my settings:

```
{
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "php": "html"
    },
    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always",


}
```

Answer (score 15):

These are the settings that fixed my problem

```
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "php": "html"
    },
    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always",
    "html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport": true,
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "php": "html"
    },
```

Comment: this worked for me however  "html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport" was an unknown configuration property....still it works without it

Comment: One hint: settings such as 'emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation' only work when using the default profile. After switching to it, everything worked fine. Too bad as I use profiles for language support and thus need to make PHP my default.

Answer (score 4):

I actually think you just need to enable tab completion to your settings.json

`"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,`

Answer (score 1):

The Emmet in PHP files should be enabled by default.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Try update to the latest version of VSCode.
Try clear out any emmet config in your user settings to let it work by default.
If it is still not working, try disable the extensions or reinstall VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem- check if have this part of code -delete this, or remove "php"

```
  "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "markdown",
    "php"
  ]
```

Comment: The original poster has included their settings, and they don't include this part.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was this setting that prevented emmet to work in PHP:

```json
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly"
```